# SQL SERVER 2012 sum values by specific datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to get some values by year and month. In a table saved some values like incoming date (datetime) and giving date (datetime) in same row are registration id and state of work( like waiting, done, ...) I need to get registration id where state of work = done and giving date is 2013-12-* *:*:* . I just need get by year = 2013 and all works, which are done in all December. I don't care which day or hour was there. I need that for university study work. PS: Sorry for really my writing skills

Comment: Oh man, it's WYSIWYG forum... so as much care you put into writing question so much you get in answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something in the lines of the following:

```
SELECT RegistrationId
FROM MyTable
WHERE StateOfWork = 'Done'
 AND YEAR(IncomingDate)=2013
 AND MONTH(IncomingDate)=12
```